# How to send parameters in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and i have a doubt.whatever we send in params[] should be our database column name? or can we send anything? if so then how can we access them in controller?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're creating or updating on an ActiveRecord model then the params will be in a nested hash. For a model called User the params hash might look like:

```
params = { :something => 'whatever', { :user => { :name => 'Flip Wilson' } } }
```

In your controller:

```
def create
  if @user = User.create(params[:user])
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass to params anything.

for examlpe - usual link: `project.dev/post?id=2&anything=true`. now you have params: `id, anything` - to get access you can insert in controller this: `params[:id]` - 2 and/or `params[:anything]` - true

also, you can pass anything to params with `link_to` method. For example: `link_to "user", users_path(id: @user.id, some: "string param", or: :symbol)`

if you want to check current params, you can insert in your current controller action this:
`raise params.inspect`